# How to redirect the output of gcc compiler to a file?

Tags: gcc

Redirection operator does not work. So how should we do it?
One more question, in makefile, how can we give arguments from command line, like

```
run: a.out
    ./a.out **<input>**
```

Comment: Please don't put unrelated questions into a single one.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

gcc prints its error messages to `stderr`, so you have to redirect `stderr`:

```
gcc -o foo foo.c 2> foo.gccmessages
```

You give arguments on the command line always in the same way

```
./a.out argument1 argument2 argument3
```

Comment: In makefile, I want to specify that input will be given from command line.I am not asking how to give input at command line? How to do that?

Comment: You do that by asking a separate question and getting answers to it.

Comment: Ok I got that, if we want to append the output to a existing file, then what should we do?

Answer (score 6):

Try:
$ make 2>&1 | tee your_build_log.txt
this will redirect stdout, 2>&1 redirects stderr to the same place as stdout while allowing you to simultaneously see the output in your terminal.

see: [How do I capture all of my compiler's output to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297536/how-do-i-capture-all-of-my-compilers-output-to-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

A detailed documentation for I/O redirection for stdout,stderr is given in this document([1](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)).Peripheral devices like stdin(eg:keyboard), stdout(eg: computer monitor) and stderr(error messages from the output of a gcc compilation) are considered as files.