# How do I capture all of my compiler's output to a file?

Tags: linux, shell, g++, makefile, io-redirection

I'm building an opensource project from source (CPP) in Linux. This is the order:

```
$CFLAGS="-g Wall" CXXFLAGS="-g Wall" ../trunk/configure --prefix=/somepath/ --host=i386-pc --target=i386-pc
$make
```

While compiling I'm getting lot of compiler warnings. I want to start fixing them. My question is how to capture all the compiler output in a file?

`$make > file` is not doing the job. It's just saving the compiler command like `g++ -someoptions /asdf/xyz.cpp` I want the output of these command executions.

Comment: Best practice recommended by the autoconf maintainers is to execute your first command differently: use '../trunk configure CFLAGS="-g Wall" CXXFLAGS="-g Wall" ...'.  That is, don't set C{XX,}FLAGS in the environment, but rather as arguments to configure.

Comment: @William Pursell, I believe pecker is, the '$' dollar sign I believe is being used to represent the shell prompt, due to the its usage on the second line (_$make_), simply without the typically space after the shell prompt.

Comment: @mctylr  "$ FOO=x cmd" is very different from "$ cmd FOO=x".  In the former, cmd is run with FOO set to "x" in the environment.  In the latter, the string "FOO=x" is an argument to cmd.

Comment: Agreed. Given the possible newness of the questioner, I was trying to be gentle.

Answer (score 130):

The compiler warnings happen on `stderr`, not `stdout`, which is why you don't see them when you just redirect `make` somewhere else. Instead, try this if you're using Bash:

```
$ make &> results.txt
```

The `&` means "redirect stdout and stderr to this location". Other shells often have similar constructs.

Comment: This is equivalent to `make > results.txt 2>&1` but with less typing :)

Comment: Is there an equivalent for pipes?

Comment: @Dana the Sane: Bash 4 has `|&` for pipes, which is equivalent to `2>&1 |`.

Comment: Please note that >&, &> and 2>&1 are all shell dependent, and may work or not depending on if you have bash/csh or other shells. 

@Alberto: I was confused too, because I was using csh and &> didn't work for me while >& worked. This was the reason.

Comment: @PiyushSoni: I was using csh and `&>` didn't work while `>&` worked.

Answer (score 29):

In a bourne shell:

```bash
make > my.log 2>&1
```

I.e. `>` redirects `stdout`, `2>&1` redirects `stderr` to the same place as `stdout`.

Comment: why executing `make 2>&1 > my.log` doesn't have the same behavior?

Answer (score 28):

Lots of good answers so far. Here's a frill:

```
$ make 2>&1 | tee filetokeepitin.txt
```

will let you watch the output scroll past.

Comment: I think that the return code of a pipeline is usually the return code of the last command; in this case, `tee` not `make`.  So the `|| more` unfortunately doesn't do what you say it does.  Compare `false || echo $?` to `false | cat || echo $?`.

Comment: @ephemient: Ah. You are right....heck, I made that work once, and now I can't recall how. In anycase, I use `tee` in this application fairly often.

Comment: `shopt -s pipefail`, perhaps?

Comment: or; "set -o pipefail"

Answer (score 7):

The output went to stderr. Use `2>` to capture that.

```
$make 2> file
```

Answer (score 6):

Assume you want to hilight warning and error from build ouput:

```
make |& grep -E "warning|error"
```

Comment: While code-only answers are not forbidden, please understand that this is a Q&A community, rather than a crowd-sourcing one, and that, usually, if the OP understood the code being posted as an answer, he/she would have come up with a similar solution on his/her own, and wouldn't have posted a question in the first place. As such, please provide *context* to your answer and/or code by explaining *how* and/or *why* it works.

Answer (score 4):

Based on an earlier reply by @dmckee

```
make | tee makelog.txt
```

This gives you real-time scrolling output while compiling, and simultaneously write to the makelog.txt file.

Answer (score 3):

Try `make 2> file`.  Compiler warnings come out on the standard error stream, not the standard output stream.  If my suggestion doesn't work, check your shell manual for how to divert standard error.

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.oreillynet.com/linux/cmd/cmd.csp?path=g/gcc

> The > character does not redirect the
>   standard error. It's useful when you
>   want to save legitimate output without
>   mucking up a file with error messages.
>   But what if the error messages are
>   what you want to save? This is quite
>   common during troubleshooting. The
>   solution is to use a greater-than sign
>   followed by an ampersand. (This
>   construct works in almost every modern
>   UNIX shell.) It redirects both the
>   standard output and the standard
>   error. For instance:
>
> ```
> $ gcc invinitjig.c >& error-msg
> ```

Have a look there, if this helps:
[another forum](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/linux-kernel/91967-gcc-output-file-makefile.html)

Answer (score 2):

In **C shell**
- The ampersand is after the greater-than symbol

```
make >& filename
```

Answer (score 2):

The below command logs the output of the 'make' command into the file 'gnu_make.log'

```
script gnu_make.log -c "make"
```

This file may contain line termination characters in dos format, to remove that the following command may be used.

```
dos2unix gnu_make.log
```

The file also may contain color-escape sequences, which works fine when viewed using 'cat' command, but if one wishes to remove those, it may be done using the below command

```
sed -i $'s/\e\\[[0-9;:]*[a-zA-Z]//g' gnu_make.log
```

Answer (score 0):

It is typically not what you want to do. You want to run your compilation in an editor that has support for reading the output of the compiler and going to the file/line char that has the problems. It works in all editors worth considering. Here is the emacs setup:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation.html

Comment: This does not answer 'How do I capture all of my compiler's output to a file?
'

Comment: When you compile within emacs, all the compiler output is captured in the  * compilation * buffer of the editor.  Saving this  buffer to a file is then, in the emacs style, a single command, C-x Cw (and choose a file name).