# Capture compilation output from script taking arguments, with stderr into log file along with looking the compilation process

Tags: csh, tcsh

I saw in this link but couldn't able to figure out how to do:
[How do I capture all of my compiler's output to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297536/how-do-i-capture-all-of-my-compilers-output-to-a-file).

I want to know how to capture all compilation logs in output file along with compilation process. Instead of makefile, I am using script. The script has few arguments.
I tried:

```
myscript.sh arg1 arg2 | tee output.log
```

but it captures all except stderr into the log.
Then I tried:

```
myscript arg1 arg2 &> output.log
```

but it won't show compilation process.

Is there any way to do both like said? Also, what will be the case in makefile instead of script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `|&` to redirect both stdout and stderr:

```
myscript.sh arg1 arg2 |& tee output.log
```

Comment: Great! That worked. Thanks. Can you give me the link or documentation on this if any?

Comment: @Ac3_DeXt3R It's in `man tcsh`; search for `|&` (use `\|&` since it's a regexp), which will give you: "Diagnostic output may be directed through a pipe with the standard output Simply use the form \`|&' rather than just \`|'." Diagnostic ouput is tcsh-speak for stderr.

Answer (score -1):

Try your first approach but redirecting stderr to stdout with `2>&1`.

Like this:

`myscript.sh arg1 arg2 2>&1 | tee output.log`