# How to redirect gcc errors to a file in Unix?

Tags: unix, gcc, io, redirect, io-redirection

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490754/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-gcc-compiler-to-a-file) but that doesn't work in Unix.

I've been running this command :

```
gcc temp.c -o temp.o 2> err.txt
```

And got the following error:

```
gcc: 2: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas what that shouldn't work? Maybe because I’m using it over a Unix server?

Comment: What shell are you running? (`echo $SHELL` may show you)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `tcsh` you don't use `2>` to redirect stderr, you use `>&` that will redirect both stdout and stderr. If you want to redirect them separately, have a look at [this quick guide](http://blog.elevenseconds.com/resources/shell-redirecting.html).

Answer (score 2):

Redirecting stderr using `2>` in tsch is not possible, but here are 2 work arounds

```
bash -c "gcc temp.c -o temp.o 2> err.txt" #if bash or sh is available
(gcc temp.c -o temp.o > /dev/null) > & err.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Yours:

```
gcc temp.c -o temp.o 2> err.txt
```

you sure mean:

```
gcc -o temp.o temp.c 2> err
```