# Log of compiling on GCC

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc

I compile some program in Ubuntu on GCC and I need that GCC write log of compiling in file. How can I do that?

Now i compile like that:

```
sudo gcc SourceFile -o WhereToCompile
```

Thanks for answer!

Comment: Do you really want to compile with `sudo`!? I highly recommend not doing that...

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490754/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-gcc-compiler-to-a-file

Comment: Yes, I need sudo. And the problem is not in SUDO.

Comment: $gcc sourcefile -o executable > logfile

Comment: @RajuKundhe `gcc sourcefile -o executable 2>> logfile` is better

Comment: If compilig is unsuccessful, I need that GCC create file with log of errors.

Comment: If you do need `sudo`, there is a serious problem in your configuration

Comment: @tyilmaz, amazing that even for such a specific but completely basic question there is a duplicate.

Comment: I try to find this solution and i didn't find it. Your soultion works, Thanks, and sorry.