# how does IDEs communicate with compilers to get error messages?

Tags: compilation, ide, ipc

i am working on a programming language project , i am coding the compiler in C++/C and and the IDE in python (tkinter) , for the communication between them i used temp files , now i am integrating native support to my language , and i want my IDE to communicate with mingw and to compile c/c++ code , but i don't know how does mingw expect me to pass arguments , i want it to compile c/c++ files without appingring a console window , and i want it to send me back the output like my compiler does , i dont know if mingw uses files or sockets to talk with IDEs . then how can  i let my IDE askes mingw to compile native code and receives the output without the appearance of a console window ? or how does IDEs ( like code::blocks , eclipse ....) communicate with the compiler ? i tried to use make files but , always there is a console window and i can't receive errors . :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found t , the solution is the use of inter-process-communication like here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687393(v=vs.85).aspx  and this helps alot [How to redirect the output of gcc compiler to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490754/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-gcc-compiler-to-a-file) after executing the compilers you need to read the stderr stream to get the output , i am answering my own question to help others