# Redirect c++ program syntax error to a file in windows

Tags: c++

I'm using Dev C++ 5.11 on windows 10 home 64 bit. While compiling the program given below, I got the error message as semi colon is missing:

> [Error] expected ';' before '}' token

I want the redirect or capture the syntax error in text file. I read about `stdout` and `stderr`, but couldn't get the output of compiler error in notepad/text file.

Comment: *"...but couldn't get the output of compiler error in notepad/text file."* Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no such option in the Dev-C++ IDE to redirect the output of `stdout` or `stderr` to a file.

But, you can do this from command line. This might help you in this regard:
[How to redirect the output of gcc compiler to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490754/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-gcc-compiler-to-a-file)

In addition, you can experiment with `Tools -> Compiler Options` to do this. I tried by adding general commands but it didn't work.

Alternatively, you can `copy` the warnings / errors by using `Copy All` option from context menu and `paste` it in a file manually.